# Why dynamic special characters are not working in my react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've a 3 components `App.js`, `SearchCategoryPage.js` & `Home.js`
On click of search icon I am not navigating to search page, why is that?

App.js

```
const outlet_id = useSelector((state) => state.outlets.selectedId);
 <Router>
        <Switch>
           <Route
            path={`/search?outlet=${outlet_id}&mode=delivery`}
            component={SearchCategoryPage}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```

Home.js

```
<Link to={`/search?outlet=${outlet_id}&mode=delivery`}>
            <img
              src={Search}
              alt="search"
              className="cursor-pointer"
              // onClick={() => setCategorySearch(true)}
            />
          </Link>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For query strings you don't need to specify it in the path in Route

so that would be

```
<Route
 path={`/search`}
 component={SearchCategoryPage}
/>
```

and in the Link component

```
<Link to={`/search?outlet=${outlet_id}&mode=delivery`}>
```